# How to default to returning errors as JSON instead of HTML with express?

Tags: node.js, express

Express by default returns errors as HTML pages. As I'm developing a REST api, I want all my errors to be in JSON format. How can i configure express for this?

I expect the response to look something like this

```
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "error": "Not Found"
}
```

but instead I get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>Cannot DELETE /object/</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my basic app

```
export const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/objects", listObjects);
app.get("/object/:id", getObject);
app.post("/object", createObject);
app.put("/object/:id", updateObject);
app.delete("/object/:id", deleteObject);
```

UPDATE:
To clarify, it is not the errors from my handlers I want to handle as json. Doing that is pretty straight forward.

What I'm after is for express to stop returning html errors for unregistered handlers, like doing DELETE on /assessments, or GET on /anUnknownRoute

Comment: post your router handling code.

Comment: I have updated the question with my app code

Comment: post your deleteObject function. how are you returning your response object.

Comment: My deleteObject function is irrelevant, because I'm not calling it.

I'm calling DELETE on /object/ which has no handler connected, instead of /object/:id. I want this error to be thrown in json format, not html

Comment: app.delete(path, callback [, callback ...]). it clearly shows that the second parameter is the callback function.  then send the json format from your deleteObject callback function.

Comment: Since I'm not adding an id after the slash it will not get called, but that's actually completely irrelevant. Read my update in the original post where I explain myself more clearly

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You add custom error handling middleware - which is regular middleware but with 4 arguments instead of 3 - to the middleware stack. In this error handler you use `res.status(code).send(jsonResponse)` to send the json error.

A simple quick example that will always send status 500 JSON errors:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')

const jsonErrorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500).send({ error: err });
}

const app = express()
// The other middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// Your handler
app.use(jsonErrorHandler)
```

Comment: haha i forgot it needed the fourth argument even if it wasnt used for it to catch errors properly, i was struggling for hours on this silly silly oversigh of mine, this answer solved my issue! thanks

Comment: Same, dont forget the `next` argument!! Thanks @xunux, you saved me a couple of hours with your coment

Comment: Why `async` on the error handler?

Comment: Sorry, this came from my code that used `await` :)

Comment: You are my hero.

Answer (score 15):

You may simply add `'Content-Type: application/json'` to your response headers and write basically anything you want in JSON format, e.g.

```
function(err, req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(500);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Or you can use `res.json` instead. Please, see official doc for more detailed information: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

If you want to return errors in JSON **by default**, then you may be interested in using default express error-handling mechanism: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Just pass an `error` to the `next` callback to go straight to the error-handler (skipping everything else in the queue in between) and add an error-handling middleware to the end of your middleware queue. This should do the trick.

P.S. From express.js FAQ:

> In Express, 404 responses are not the result of an error, so the error-handler middleware will not capture them. This behavior is because a 404 response simply indicates the absence of additional work to do; in other words, Express has executed all middleware functions and routes, and found that none of them responded. All you need to do is add a middleware function at the very bottom of the stack (below all other functions) to handle a 404 response:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
})
```

Obviously, you may send a response in JSON format...

Comment: I might have failed to explain my problem clearly. I know how to return json errors for any given route. But when, for example, no route is hit, express throws its own errors. These are plain html, but I want them in json.

Comment: @Jakob you could add a middleware that would match any of non-matched requests (`app.use('/', ...) {}`). And then it converges to the same idea I wrote above.

Comment: The last line does solve my specific problem, but introduces a new one. The OPTIONS call to an existing endpoint no longer works. I'm guessing there could be other unwanted behaviours as well. Manually responding to OPTIONS in my router feels like a real step down. 

Is there really no way in express to controll non-matched requests without ruining other behaviours?

Comment: @Jakob Yeap, my bad. It should not really be that complicated. Check out express.js FAQ. They provide crystal-clear explanation on how express.js handles 404s. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html

Comment: Thanks for being so persistent, but your latest solution still breaks the OPTIONS call to valid endpoints. Really strange that such solutions are in the official docs

Comment: @Jakob Could you please write down some code on how you reproduce this issue. It sounds like a real bug in the most popular Node.js framework :D I also admit that the unexpected behaviour is caused by some code you haven't mentioned yet.

Comment: This is literally the whole app: https://gist.github.com/Jakst/5bb4645f154eef8a6b6050d959ad3807


Doing an OPTIONS call on /ping returns `nope`, but if you remove `app.use(...)` it returns `GET,HEAD`.

Comment: Thank you i puted your code in bottom of my middllewares and it works : app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
})

Comment: I did some checking in the express.js source. The reason why it all ends up in HTML format is because they call `finalhandler` by default, (see https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js), which produces the final output on HTML format only (OT: The `NODE_ENV` variable is handled by Finalhandler, not Express). Finalhandler package is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/finalhandler.

Comment: In Express, 404 responses are not the result of an error, so the error-handler middleware will not capture them - Really useful many thx

Answer (score 2):

all you have to do for getting JSON response for errors is to add another argument in the route handler that will be a middle-ware function responsible for errors.

Ex:
you have to modify this

```
app.get('/objects', listObjects);
```

to be like that:

```
app.get('/objects', listObjects, (err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send({error: err.message})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following middleware to your express configuration:

```
const jsonErrorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status).send({
    status: err.status,
    message: err.message,
  });
  return next();
};
app.use(jsonErrorHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Express, 404 responses are not the result of an error, so the error-handler middleware will not capture them. This behavior is because a 404 response simply indicates the absence of additional work to do; in other words, Express has executed all middleware functions and routes, and found that none of them responded. All you need to do is add a middleware function at the very bottom of the stack (below all other functions) to handle a 404 response.

```js
// root/src/middleware/notFoundHandlerMiddleware.ts

import { Http } from '@common/http';

const NotFoundHandlerMiddleware = (function() {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(Http.NOTFOUND.statusCode).json({ ...Http.NOTFOUND });
  };
})();

export { NotFoundHandlerMiddleware };
```

```js
// root/main.ts
...
app.use('/api', [AuthRouter, UserRouter, PostRouter]);
app.use(NotFoundHandlerMiddleware);
app.use(ErrorHandlerMiddleware);
...
```